# Strange behavior with the redirects in Store views, Cms pages, Cookies

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, session, store-view, cookie

#### Config :

**Front :** I have Two store views `1:simple`, `2:pro`.

**Admin :** `1Website->1StoreGroup->2Storeviews`: `simple` and `pro`

**Cms Pages :** I created different Cms pages, let's taking for example : `2 (A,B)` for `simple view` and `2 (C,D)` for `pro view` (Content->Pages->cmsPage->Website page->set `Simple` for the first two and `Pro` for the other two).

---

**Practical case :**

In front When I switch to the **Simple** storeView `?___store=simple` I find my two pages (A,B) and also with `?___store=pro` I find my two other pages (C,D) Great.

Now When I click on the A page, I get it cool, but when I switch to the other store view `pro` and I click on C page It redirect to the simple store one with 404 page not found (404 because the page was configured just for the pro one), Im obliged to set for each time the storeView `a?___store=simple`, `c?___store=pro` etc... and I don't need that, it's not normal.

Why It redirects to the first one (the default one) ? from the moment I changed the store, this one is saved in a cookie and Magento logically is able to recover the current store view, here is not the case.

I checked the cookies config with an empty value, domaine value, flush the caches, reindex etc... but without success.

Comment: Did you managed to resolve this issue ? I'm having same issue with category. I've 4 store views with 1 website and 1 store. If I am in english store than everything working fine I can visit category, But as soon as I switch to other store view than it redirect me to home page and I cant able to visit category. Even adding direct URL's to browser. this happens on all store views expect english. If you solved this problem Please post your answer.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't solve it, I moved on to something else. I was obliged to suffix that urls with `?___store=storecode`